# Update table variable with results from another table from query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table variable `@WEEKS_MONTH` like this:

[image]

I must update this table (column `SUMMARY`) with query:

```
SELECT SUM(AVAI_NUM)
FROM SCAVAI
WHERE AVAI_DST >= (SELECT WEEKSTART 
                   FROM @WEEKS_MONTH 
                   WHERE WEEKOFMONTH = 1) 
  AND AVAI_DST <= (SELECT WEEKEND 
                   FROM @WEEKS_MONTH 
                   WHERE WEEKOFMONTH = 1)
```

Problem that I have is that I don't know how to connect that table with this query. (`WEEKOFMONTH` must be from table, row by row. For example I've just put number 1.)

Comment: To be clear, the table at the top *is* the `@WEEKS_MONTH` table in the query you've shown?

Comment: yes, sorry I've forgotten to include this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a subquery in an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE wm
SET Summary = (SELECT SUM(s.AVAI_NUM)
               FROM SCAVAI s
               WHERE s.AVAI_DST BETWEEN wm.WEEK_START and wm.WEEK_END)
FROM @WEEKS_MONTH wm
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my problem. @Damien if you can please look into my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836437/update-table-from-udf-results