# Update table from UDF results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `@ROOMS_BY_DEPA_KEY1` like this:

```
DECLARE @ROOMS_BY_DEPA_KEY1 TABLE
(               
    OPRO_KEY INT,               
    KAPACITETA INT,             
    WEEK_1 DECIMAL(8,2),
    WEEK_2 DECIMAL(8,2),
    WEEK_3 DECIMAL(8,2),
    WEEK_4 DECIMAL(8,2),
    WEEK_5 DECIMAL(8,2),
    WEEK_6 DECIMAL(8,2)
)

INSERT INTO @ROOMS_BY_DEPA_KEY1(OPRO_KEY)
VALUES (160000014),(160000015),(160000016),(160000017),(160000018),(160000019),(160000020)
```

So after filling some data table looks like this:

[image]

I must update each rows columns `WEEK_1`, `WEEK_2`, `WEEK_3`, `WEEK_4`, `WEEK_5`, `WEEK_6` with results from this table, which is being generated from `OPRO_KEY` and `KAPACITETA`:

```
DECLARE @WEEKS_MONTH AS DBO.WEEKS_MONTH_Type
(
    WEEKOFMONTH INT,
    WEEKSTART DATE,
    WEEKEND DATE, 
    NO_DAYS INT, 
    AVERAGE_AVAI DECIMAL(8,2)
)
```

(it's table type because it's being used as functions parameter). Results from that table looks like this:

[image]

To get this second table I have a UDF:

```
dbo.f_SCAVAI_GetWeekAverage(@iOPRO_KEY, @WEEKS_MONTH, '1', @iKAPACITETA)
```

Table `@WEEKS_MONTH` is filled with some values (weekofmonth, datestart, dateend, no_days) and it stays the same for each call:

[image]

My problem is how to call this function for each `OPRO_KEY` and how to update week columns from returning table? 
Columns are updated according to `WEEKOFMONTH`. Example: `WEEK_1` update where `@WEEK_MONTHS.WEEK_OF_MONTH` = 1, `WEEK_2` where `@WEEK_MONTHS` = 2

Comment: Please write your data test as text, not images... Or better directlyas INSERT INTO: in this way is easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I've already corrected my question.

Comment: `PIVOT` sounds like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you will always have exactly 6 weeks, the simplest way to update the @ROOMS_BY_DEPA_KEY1 table would be using a pivot of the @Weeks_Month table:

```
UPDATE @ROOMS_BY_DEPA_KEY1
SET Week_1 = w.Week_1
    ,Week_2 = w.Week_2
    ,Week_3 = w.Week_3
    ,Week_4 = w.Week_4
    ,Week_5 = w.Week_5
    ,Week_6 = w.Week_6
FROM 
   (SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT 'Week_' + CAST(WeekOfMonth AS VARCHAR) AS WeekName
            ,Average_Avai
        FROM @WEEKS_MONTH) wm
    PIVOT (MAX(Average_Avai) 
           FOR WeekName IN (Week_1, Week_2, Week_3, Week_4, Week_5, Week_6)
          )p
    ) w
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the problem with:

```
UPDATE RM
                SET RM.WEEK_1 = (
                    SELECT P.AVERAGE_AVAI FROM dbo.f_SCAVAI_GetWeekAverage(RM.DEPA_KEY, RM.OPRO_KEY, @WEEKS_MONTH, @cWorkDaysOnly, RM.KAPACITETA) P WHERE P.WEEKOFMONTH = 1
                ),
                RM.WEEK_2 = (
                    SELECT P.AVERAGE_AVAI FROM dbo.f_SCAVAI_GetWeekAverage(RM.DEPA_KEY,RM.OPRO_KEY, @WEEKS_MONTH, @cWorkDaysOnly, RM.KAPACITETA) P WHERE P.WEEKOFMONTH = 2
                ),
                RM.WEEK_3 = (
                    SELECT P.AVERAGE_AVAI FROM dbo.f_SCAVAI_GetWeekAverage(RM.DEPA_KEY,RM.OPRO_KEY, @WEEKS_MONTH, @cWorkDaysOnly, RM.KAPACITETA) P WHERE P.WEEKOFMONTH = 3
                ),
                RM.WEEK_4 = (
                    SELECT P.AVERAGE_AVAI FROM dbo.f_SCAVAI_GetWeekAverage(RM.DEPA_KEY,RM.OPRO_KEY, @WEEKS_MONTH, @cWorkDaysOnly, RM.KAPACITETA) P WHERE P.WEEKOFMONTH = 4
                ),
                RM.WEEK_5 = (
                    SELECT P.AVERAGE_AVAI FROM dbo.f_SCAVAI_GetWeekAverage(RM.DEPA_KEY,RM.OPRO_KEY, @WEEKS_MONTH, @cWorkDaysOnly, RM.KAPACITETA) P WHERE P.WEEKOFMONTH = 5
                ),
                RM.WEEK_6 = (
                    SELECT P.AVERAGE_AVAI FROM dbo.f_SCAVAI_GetWeekAverage(RM.DEPA_KEY,RM.OPRO_KEY, @WEEKS_MONTH, @cWorkDaysOnly, RM.KAPACITETA) P WHERE P.WEEKOFMONTH = 6
                )
                FROM @ROOMS_BY_DEPA_KEY1 RM
```